# How get block number for certain address, when this address was created?

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I need to write a function that will return the block number in which the address was created.

Answer (score 0):

An address is not created inside a block... an address is just a public key generated outside the blockchain. Inside blocks you have transactions, and **the creation of an address is not a transaction**. The closest to what you asked, could be **"first time an address has been seen/used"**. In that case, there is not a single web3 call that can be of help, you may have to implement a loop to check all blocks and all transactions inside each block starting from block 0, and stop as soon as you find the first occurrence of the address you are looking for. Be warned that this can be very slow depending on how soon or late in the history of Eth your address has been used, unless you add external indexes and so on. You can find more info here: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/580